# Django doesn't seem to mock model methods

Tags: python, django, mocking, pytest, pytest-django

I am trying to write some test cases for the following method as part of a model called Project:

```
    def get_mouse_model_designs(self):
        return {details.design.to_mouse_model()
                for details in self.strategies.all()}
```

The trouble seems to be in the `details.design.to_mouse_model()` and I cannot seem to accurately mock this function. This is the test I have (`self.details2` is the only model linked to the project in this test case, so it would be the only record returned by `self.strategies.all()`):

```
    def test_mouse_model_designs_one_design(self):
        mm_design = MagicMock()
        self.details2.design.to_mouse_model = MagicMock(return_value=mm_design)
        self.assertEqual(self.project2.get_mouse_model_designs(), {mm_design})
```

And here is the error message I get:

```
AssertionError: Items in the first set but not the second:
<MouseModel.LabWork.DesignTask.DesignTask object at 0x0A4B0910>
Items in the second set but not the first:
<MagicMock id='172651760'>
```

A MouseModel.LabWork.DesignTask.DesignTask object is what is returned by the `to_mouse_model()` method. But I mocked this out. So from the error message I can see that it is not actually mocking the `to_mouse_model()` method. I have tried to assert that the method was called and that fails also.

However, if I remove the `to_mouse_model()` in the function definition and update the test accordingly it passes.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution. By mocking the class method rather than the object method:

```
@patch("LabWork.models.Design.to_mouse_model")
def test_mouse_model_designs_one_design(self, mock_design_mm):
    mm_design = MagicMock()
    mock_design_mm.return_value = mm_design
    self.assertEqual(self.project2.get_mouse_model_designs(), {mm_design})
```